# Using the UPS API in the Shopify script editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopifyscripts

I need to use the UPS shipping API in the Script Editor in the Shopify. In the Script Editor only the `Ruby` programming language.

I have a task to determine the address type *Residential* or *Commercial* on the `checkout` page. I was told that you can use Script Editor (`Ruby`) to make edits to the `checkout` page, but I'm not sure if can use this. The UPS shipping API documentation also lacks `Ruby` language examples.

Please tell me if I can use UPS shipping API using `Ruby` language in the Script Editor?

I really need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. You can change pricing offered by UPS, but you would be setting up the actual rates returned by UPS in your Shipping setup in the Admin. Scripting is meant more to show hide options, re-order options and or discount them. It not meant to make outside API calls to services.

So you can easily inspect the UPS rates your shipping setup returns for a customer, and you can decide whether to show or hide some of them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have a sample rate check code example? I have absolutely no knowledge of Ruby.

Comment: Shopify offers many examples. Just click the links in the Script Editor to the API and choose Shipping and you'll see lots of examples.